# Android Studio warns that value cannot be null, however, it can. Is it something wrong with compiler?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I'm using the latest version of Android Studio.
When coding today, I found an interesting warning it gave me. So on line 45, I've got a code

```
categoryAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

It says that `categoryAdapter cannot be null`, however, it can, as clearly seen on the second screenshot.

[image]
[image]

The setter on categories is called before `categoryAdapter` was initialised and thus it's null (what makes sense), as seen on the 3rd screenshot (`categoryAdapter` is initialised on the line 87). 
Is it a bug in compiler?

[image]

Comment: Please include relevant code as text in your question. Please DO NOT post screenshots of your code.

Comment: Yeah, I marker categoryAdapter with question mark '?'.
The intent of this topic was to understand why compiler gives the warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a design issue, but I don't see any better alternative to what the compiler currently does.

When method bodies are checked, it's basically assumed the instance is fully constructed. Otherwise *any* access to `categoryAdapter` from any method would need to be marked with `?` just in case you call this method in the constructor before initializing `categoryAdapter`.

Maybe the compiler could treat methods called in `init` blocks specially, at least non-`open` ones.

Answer (score 1):

You don't define `CategoryAdapter` as nullable. In order for it to be nullable you have to give it a type of `CategoryAdapter?`. I suspect the reason it's not complaining that you haven't initialized it is because you've marked it with @get:Bindable.

I suggest that it may be better to make the variable a `lateinit var` rather than a `non-nullable val`. Vals are immutable so you won't be able to assign it a value anyway.

Comment: No, it isn't complaining because it _is_ initialized in the `init` block.

Comment: exactly, Alexey, that's the reason why it's not complaining.

Comment: The fact remains, you don't define CategoryAdapter as nullable. Therefore it cannot be null, which is why it's telling you that the `?` is unnecessary.